# Handling Numverify API error in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, api, error-handling

I'm trying to implement a feature in my app where the phone number  type (mobile, landline, tollfree) is verified with [Numverify API](https://apilayer.com/marketplace/number_verification-api?utm_source=apilayermarketplace&utm_medium=featured). I want to handle errors gracefully i.e. invalid API key, exceeded the amount of request/month, etc, inside my Javascript code but the error is not caught by the try/catch:

```js
const url_line_type = `https://api.apilayer.com/number_verification/validate?number=${phoneNumber}&country_code=CA`;
    try {
        const response = await axios.create().get(url_line_type, {
            headers: {
                apikey: "<my-api-key>"
            }
        });
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

and instead bubbles up and is caught by xhr.

From what I read this is the default behavior with external code called in async function; it doesn't get handled by try/catch.
I've then tried to check the response status code for 4XX codes but the error still get caught by xhr.
The app functions without error handling but leaves data in a undefined state while still having the xhr error.

I'm wondering if there is a good way to handle these errors as to not let my app in a undefined state.